# Constructor injecting make MissingBinding in dagger 2 and mvp

Tags: dagger-2, android-mvp

I have created simple project with dagger2 and mvp.

This is my component :

```
@MainScope
@Component(modules = {MainModule.class})
public interface IMainComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

and This is MainModule.class:

```
@Module
public class MainModule {

    @MainScope
    @Provides
    IMain.IMainModel model() {
        return new MainModel();
    }
}
```

Now in presenter i want to inject presenter from it's constructor so i do :

```
public class MainPresenter implements IMain.IMainPresenter {
    IMain.IMainModel model;
    IMain.IMainView view;

    @Inject
    public MainPresenter(IMain.IMainModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
```

But i got This error:

```
  symbol:   class DaggerIMainComponent
  location: package com.safarayaneh.engineer.main.di
E:\Projects\Android\NewEng\Engineer\engineer\src\main\java\com\safarayaneh\engineer\main\di\IMainComponent.java:9: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.safarayaneh.engineer.main.mvp.IMain.IMainPresenter cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

When make `provider` in  MainModule.class to create presenter and remove `@Inject` above presenter constructor , everything is fine:
@Module

```
public class MainModule {

    @MainScope
    @Provides
    IMain.IMainModel model() {
        return new MainModel();
    }


    @MainScope
    @Provides
    IMain.IMainPresenter presenter(IMain.IMainModel model) {
        return new MainPresenter(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: To fix problem with missing provider of `IMain.IMainPresenter` in first scenario, you can add `@MainScope
    @Provides
    IMain.IMainPresenter presenter(MainPresenter presenter) { return presenter; }` in `MainModule` - that should helps dagger to find out provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your Activity expects `IMain.IMainPresenter`, but if you just annotate the constructor then what's placed on the objects graph is the concrete `MainPresenter`.

You've got three options here:

1. Use explicit provider method (as you did)
2. Use `@Binds` annotation inside the module to specify that `MainPresenter` should be provided as `IMain.IMainPresenter`
3. Don't use interface for the presenter